# How to test a method which does not return anything?

Tags: java, junit

I want to test following code. But as it does always return a message **migration completed** therefore, how would I be sure if exception was thrown and if it went through catch block.

In simple words I do not have anything to assert.

Note: I am not allowed to append an extra message to my return message, it should always be **migration completed**

```
if (sourceCampaign.getId() > 0 || collect.size() > 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("ids are positive"); 

} catch(IllegalStateException e) {        
    logger.error("error", "Migration error, IDs are positive");                             
}

return("migration completed");
```

Please be patient as I am new in programing world.

Comment: The only testable thing about that method is that it always returns that string and that it doesn't throw any exception. There's not much else you can test about it. Not in a *unit* test, anyway. That's just a badly designed method, IMHO.

Comment: Why do you return migration completed when you have errors? You should report that you had errors, and that's testable!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have already spent 5 hours on it and tried to convince my team lead but He thinks I am a bad programmer, I proposed him this we should not ctach exception and instead as can use expected=illegalStateexception in Test but I couldnt convince,

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire for that a separate email is sent to user with detailed logs

Comment: @Maria don't quote me on this but, *if you can* (and I can't stress this **if** enough), go as far as possible from that team/organization/whatever as possible.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the code is written doesn't make it easy to test.
An alternative answer to the ones you have already received is to rewrite it to something more testable:

```
try {
   validate( sourceCampaign, collect);
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {
   manage(e);
}
finally {
   return("migration completed");
}

public void validate(...) throws IllegalStateException {
   if (sourceCampaign.getId() > 0 || collect.size() > 0) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("ids are positive"); 
   }
}

public void manage(Exception e) {
   logger.error("error", "Migration error, IDs are positive");
}
```

Now that they are separated in different methods, you can test that each part works in the expected way and you can also mock them by extending the original class.

One way to test that the `validate` method throw an exception in JUnit 4 is to use the rule `ExpectedException`:

```
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void testIllegalStateException() throws Exception {
        thrown.expect( IllegalStateException.class );
  
        ...
        new ClassName().validate( sourceCampaign, collect );
    }
```

There is no easy way, as far as I know, to test with a unit test that the log message is printed.

Note that I don't think you need to throw an exception in this case and you could log the error if the condition is not met. But somebody else already provided that answer.

Comment: Thankyou So so Much, I really really appreciate your time and guidance, you saved my so many hours, your solution works as a charm. we Need more people like you who actually help and not thumbs down @Davide

Comment: Maybe you can mark this as the correct answer? The question was a bit tricky though

Comment: Yeh Sure, I have a new Question @Davide

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this method should be improved.  Don't use exceptions for control flow.  Since the exception is thrown and caught under a specific condition, just use that condition:

```
if (sourceCampaign.getId() > 0 || collect.size() > 0) {
    logger.error("error", "Migration error, IDs are positive");
}
return("migration completed");
```

Now, as for testing, there are two things you'd need to cover:

1. The method returns the expected result (this is an easy test, since this method always ever returns the exact same thing).
2. The method invokes expected functionality.

The second one is right here:

```
logger.error("error", "Migration error, IDs are positive");
```

You'd need to test that, when provided which `souceCampaign` and/or `collect` values which meet the expected criteria, that the `error()` method is invoked on `logger`.  You would do this by supplying the object with a *mock* instance for `logger`.

Java has a variety of mocking libraries available (I've used Mockito in the past and it's done the job well).  And depending on your architecture you may also want to start learning about Dependency Injection.  (Or at least the Dependency Inversion Principle, if not any particular Dependency Injection framework.)  But with a mocked `logger` you can assert that specific operations were invoked on that mock.

Comment: The log statement should be changed to `logger.error("Migration error, IDs are positive", e);`

Comment: @David Thankyou, I was implementing your solution but then other David proposed a solution too thankyou so much